# Sparse least squares with a (black-box) ill-conditioned operator

Tags: sparse-matrix, least-squares, condition-number

It was suggested on  math.stackexchange.com that I try to ask this question here.

Consider a bounded linear operator $A : U \to V$ where $U$ is finite dimensional and where $V$ is a separable Hilbert space, or with large dimension such that $A$ cannot be stored explicitly, being instead available as an algorithm for computing $y \mapsto Ay$. Let $f \in V$ and consider the standard least-squares problem: Find $x \in U$ such that $\|Ax-f\|=\text{min}!$. We assume that inner products of columns of $A$, i.e., the matrix elements of $M = A^*A$, can be computed efficiently, and similarly $A^*f$ can be computed efficiently. However, we also assume that that $M = A^*A$ is ill-conditioned.

Are there efficient algorithms for the solution of this least-squares problem that avoids the ill-conditioning of $A$?

*Additional details added in edit:*

In my concrete example, $A$ is on the form
$$ Ae_i = u_i \in V = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),$$
with prescribed vectors $u_i$, and where $\{e_i\}$ is some orthornormal basis for $U$. The normal equations read
$$ Mx = A^* f, \quad M = A^* A,$$
which takes the usual matrix form when we expand $x = \sum_i x_i e_i$, and introduce
the matrix with elements $M_{ij} = \langle u_i,u_j\rangle_{L^2}$, and the vector $(A^*f)_i = \langle u_i, f \rangle_{L^2}$.  Thus, the normal equation is easy to write down and solve *if* $M$ is not ill-conditioned. However, it turns out in practice to be. The LSQR algorithm mentioned in the comments does not seem viable here, as it requires an algorithm for $u \mapsto A^* u$.

To be even more concrete, in the $V = L^2(\mathbb{R})$ case, I have $n = 3K$ basis functions. The first $K$ basis functions are gaussian functions $u_i(x) = \exp(-\alpha_i(x-z_i)^2)$, with $\alpha_i,z_i\in\mathbb{C}$. The remaining $2K$ basis functions are the derivatives of $u_i$ with respect to the complex parameters. Moreover, $f\in L^2$ is a function for which I have an algorithm for computing $\langle u_i, f\rangle_{L^2}$, $1\leq i \leq 3K$. Note that inner products of any pair of gaussians and their derivatives are readily computed, so I also have an algorithm for $M = A^* A$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're right to be concerned about the conditioning of $A^*A$. I think some kind of incremental SVD could help -- see [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/incremental-svd-implementation-in-matlab) or [this paper](https://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2002-24.pdf).

Comment: Is the matrix $A$ sparse?

Comment: In my edit I tried to explain my concrete problem. The matrix $A$ must really be considered an operator: When acting on a vector it gives a linear combination of some fixed Hilbert space vectors (actually, gaussian functions). So $A$ is in a sense sparse, but is not represented by a matrix.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to compute elements of $M=A^{*}A$ here.  You will need the ability to compute the adjoint operator $z \rightarrow A^{*}z$.  With that, you can use a matrix-free iterative least-squares algorithm like LSQR.  Because your problem is ill-conditioned, you'll need to add some regularization (this is available as an option in LSQR.)

Comment: Thanks! LSQR seems interesting. However, in my case, $A$ in facts maps into a Hilbert space, so the action of $A^*$ cannot really be considered and I believe the conditions of the algorithm are not satisfied. I will check though.

Comment: You can also regularize the normal equations by solving $(M+\lambda^{2} I) x=A^{*}f$.  This is equivalent to minimizing $\min \| Ax - f \|^{2}+\lambda^{2} \| x \|^{2}$.  You really need to consider why this least-squares problem is ill-conditioned and whether regularization is appropriate and exactly what regularization to use.

Comment: In the question, you state that you can find $A^{*}f$.  If so, you can use the same approach within an iterative least squares solver.

Comment: I sort of understand where the ill-conditioning comes from. My condition numbers are in the $10^{20}$ range, and seem to be even larger in some cases. By basis functions that comprise $A$ are gaussians and their derivatives with respect to, say, the center of the gaussian. Thus, I can compute $A^*f$ for $f$ being gaussian or certain other special functions, but not general $f$...

Comment: I know that the basis vectors are linearly independent in exact arithmetic, and finding a preconditioner should amount to taking clever linear combinations of the basis functions.

Comment: These are the kind of details that should be added to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I added some details in a second edit.